# get item[i] from a listview using threads

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I have a function like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in getListViewItems(listView2)) //for proxy
{
    if (reader.Peek() == -1)
    {
        break;
    }

    lock (reader)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }


    //proxy code
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    if (item != null)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++)
        {
            if (item.SubItems[s].Text != null)
            {
                mylist.Add(item.SubItems[s].Text);
            }
            else
            {
                mylist.Add("");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    //end proxy code


    //some other code including the threadpool
}
```

and the delegate code:

```
private delegate ListView.ListViewItemCollection GetItems(ListView lstview);
private ListView.ListViewItemCollection getListViewItems(ListView lstview)
{
    ListView.ListViewItemCollection temp = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(new ListView());
    if (!lstview.InvokeRequired)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lstview.CheckedItems)
        {
            temp.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
       return (ListView.ListViewItemCollection)this.Invoke(new GetItems(getListViewItems), new object[] { lstview });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I wanna replace that foreach loop in the main function with a conditional function:

```
if (reader.Peek() == -1)
{
    break;
}

lock (reader)
{
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}


if (use_proxy == true)
{
    mylist2 = get_current_proxy();
}

//some other code including the threadpool

private List<string> get_current_proxy()
{
    //what shall I add here?
}
```

How can I make that function do the same as foreach loop but using for loop? I mean getting the proxies one by one ...

Answer (score 2):

I see multiple questions revolving around an idea of scraping a website for emails then spamming.  You have very cool tools for that already, no need for a new one.

Anyway - I don't understand your question, and it seems that I'm not the only one here, but the thing you'll have to KNOW before anything else is:

**Having ANYTHING in Windows run in multiple threads will ultimately have to be synchronized when you do `Invoke()` which HAVE TO wait until it all passes through ONE thread and that's the one that holds a message loop.  So you can try to read from or write to `ListView` from multiple threads, but to do each read/write you'll have to `Invoke()` (you probably tried it directly and BAAAAM) and every Invoke() has only ONE hole to go through, and all your threads will have to wait their turn.**

Next: having ListView to be a CONTAINER for your data is so BAD I can't even comment any further.  Consider something as a

```
class MyData
{
    public string Name;
    public string URL;
    // ...
}
```

and

```
List<MyData> _myData;
```

to hold your data.  You'll be able to access it from multiple threads, if you take care of some low-key sync issues.

Lastly, how come you ask us questions about .net C# programming if you don't even know the syntax.  Well, it's rhetorical, ...